# SpringData wrong results using native query and date property

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data and I use native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT(t.foo_id) FROM t_bar t where time > ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getFoo(DateTime after);
```

For example this returns `3` results.

Native query directly in mysql server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.foo_id) FROM t_bar t where time > '2016-08-16T11:44:00.002+02:00'
```

returns `0` results.

Dates are equals for both.

The results are different than using pure sql query, looks `time` property is not used or wrong. What's wrong ?

**Edit:**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT(t.foo_id) FROM t_bar t where time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL ?1 HOUR)", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getFoo(int lastHours);
```

Returns correct results.

But still problem exist, what can cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ithink you should use ?0 instead of ?1

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT(t.foo_id) FROM t_bar t where time > ?0", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getFoo(DateTime after);
```

this is an example from http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?0", nativeQuery = true)
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: I think it's misspelling in documentation, all other indexes starts from 1 in examples. Also I had error if I remember related to this. Also my 3rd example returns correct result with ?1 argument. I will confirm it in the evening.

Comment: As I said before, there is misspelling in documentation, it counts from 1, with 0 throws an exception